# ReactJS: How to prevent duplicate values in array.push?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, array-push

While selecting one option in the Select box at that time rest of the options are become multiple values. How can i prevent this duplicate values ?

```
import Select from 'react-select';
const dataOptions = []; 
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.data = [];
        this.getData();
    }
    getData = () => { api.request({url: `/getdata`}).then(res => res.map(el => this.data[el.id] = el.name)) }

    addData = () => {
        const { selectedId } = this.state;
        var datas = this.data;
        console.log(datas);
        datas.map((name, index) => {
            if (!dataOptions.includes(name)) {
                console.log('b4 push:', dataOptions)
                dataOptions.push({ value: index, label: name });
                console.log('aftr push:', dataOptions)
            }
        });
        return (
            <Select options={dataOptions}
            isMulti
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Something is wrong happening in this syntax:

```
datas.map((name, index) => {
  if (!dataOptions.includes(name)) {
       dataOptions.push({ value: index, label: name });
  }
});
```

Console Results

```
[ "data-1", "data-2", "data-3"]

b4 push: [
  {value: 1, label: "data-1"}
  {value: 2, label: "data-2"}
  {value: 3, label: "data-3"}
]

aftr push: [
  {value: 1, label: "data-1"}
  {value: 2, label: "data-2"}
  {value: 3, label: "data-3"}
]
```

P.S: Here in aftr push i have already selected first option from drop down; so in result if should not be displayed in the array values.

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Using `.map()` you need to return something, for what you are doing there you can change `.map()` to `.forEach()`, in foreach you don't need to return anything.

Comment: can you post sample `data`?

Comment: @Shubh it's not working; using this results are not displaying.

Comment: Please post the sample data then,because if you are using destructring assignment that should be the syntax.

Comment: @Shubh Please review updated data.

Comment: Please post a json format data ,as I cant recreate the issue with the picture.See the updated answer

Comment: do: `if(!dataOptions.includes({value: index, label: name})) {` ...

Comment: @Evhz that wont work because both the reference of objects will be different . They would be different objects.For reference look here-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748605/does-include-works-with-array-of-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `destructuring` syntax should be like below

```
datas.map(({name, index}) => {
      if (!dataOptions.includes(name)) {
           dataOptions.push({ value: index, label: name });
      }
    });
```

Moreover you don't need external array to push the data inside map function as the function by default returns an array, you can do simply like below

```
 let expected_data=datas.map(({name, index}) => {
              if (!dataOptions.includes(name)) {
                 return  { value: index, label: name };// return a value
              }
            });
```

The `expected_data` will contain the data you need after operation

See the snippet-

```js
let data = [{
  "name": 1,
  "index": 2
}, {
  "name": 11,
  "index": 21
}]

console.log(data.map(({
  index,
  name
}) => {

  return {
    value: index,
    label: name
  }

}))
```

You better use `Array.some()` for what you are looking

```
 datas.map((name,index) => { // here index is the iterator
                if(!dataOptions.some(({value,label})=>label==name  ))
            {
                   dataOptions.push({ value: index, label: name });
              }
            });
```

Comment: That doesn't work as [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) would not return results if you search a string inside an array of objects, regardless those objects have strings or pears.

Comment: And how can you be so sure that the dataOptions is array of objects ?? @Evhz

Comment: You are confused ,dataoptions is an object array ,you cant use includes just to check if a primitive value exists in it .Please specify which key of dataoption you wanna check value or label?

Comment: Doesn't matter; my result should be like this: if i select an option from any drop down values then the rest of values can not be duplicated... So currently if i select value 1 then other two values become duplicates and it becomes total 4 values with duplication.

Comment: No records are fetching using this method in select box, i also tried like this: 
` if(dataOptions.some(({value,label}) => { value == index, label == name }  )) `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202147/discussion-between-aananddham-and-shubh).

Comment: `[ "data-1", "data-2", "data-3"]` is this your datas array?w hich you are using with map function